# php save text of any file is not working appropriately?

Tags: php, sql, file, pdf, text

I want to create file sharing platform but php has some bug about it.I just use fread to get text of any file `(exe,pdf,docx,ppt and etc)` then I create text file with random name and with `.txt` extension.So when user want to download this file ,I create random folder and inside of that folder I create file which has same text that user want to download , and then I give extension which is same as user uploaded version of file and force user to download it.
But when user download file,for example zip file and then if user wants to open , it says failed to open because not supported format.This happens when I try to do this with docx,pdfs,zips and that kind of files (not txt,html,css,c files).

Example : *I force the user to download with same extension that he uploaded, for example if user uploaded zip file,I read the text with fread then save this text in the db or text file,and then if user wants to download that file, I just create file and give it zip extension, then force the user to download it,but once user upload this file then if user want to open it fails, but it should open zip file because content text of this file is exact same as user uploaded to the server*

Answer should contain:

1)Why this happens?How to fix it?

2)What is the ideal solution?

3)is it safe to do this?

Comment: good thing that you set the standards for answers when this question makes no sense in the first place , why do consider executable or files containing binary or whatever to be text ? can't you just create a zip file and add the uploaded file there ?

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix Thank you.yeah I can do this but I need to be able to read these files , because I will show content of this file to the user, it can be with a different ways , for example if it is pdf, when I finish my pdf reader it will be readable,when it is zip it will not have preview, this can be similar to dropbox .For example if I upload zip to the dropbox then if I rename it to the txt file , it shows me text content , I think I can store any file with that way so when My reader is ready I can use for each format in the future.But that problem occured

Answer (score 0):

1. This happens, because windows knows the app to open file file just from the extension. If you rename the file to something.txt, then the editor always wants to open it.
2. There's no such thing as an *ideal* solution. A soltution would be to store the file with the original name (maybe at some unique part to prevent duplicates) in a non public readable directory without execution bit set. To access the file, you could create a proxy script, which returns the file and appens a should download header (and maybe the original filename).
3. Its as safe, as you implement it. Your current solution could be safe, the solution I posted could be safe - but without knowing the details, how you implemented it, nobody knows, if it is actually safe.

Comment: No I actually force the user to download with same extension that he uploaded, for example if user uploaded zip file,I read the text with fread then save this text in the db or text file,and then if user wants to download that file, I just create file and give it zip extension, then force the user to download it,but once user upload this file then if user want to open it fails, but it should open zip file because content text of this file is exact same as user uploaded to the server

Comment: And you are sure, you have no problems with the encoding or that the database field isn't to small to keep all content?

Comment: Even to be sure that this file is contain as same as uploaded version ,I changed extension of real file (which will be uploaded) then I copy the text and paste it to the downloaded version and then I change extesion for both , real file worked, downloaded again failed

Comment: I have some encoding  problems I will open another question for that, but it seems that there is another problem because I copied old file text and paste it to downloaded file and it again failed

Answer (score 0):

1. It happens because you are opening binary files like a zip file and storing it in a text file then streaming it with the zip extension again.
2. The ideal solution would be to use one of the 1 million open source file managers out there with proven records and big developer communities. But if for some reason you want to build your own, save the files in a safe folder outside your public folder. store the path in a database of choice together with the public path you will show your users. Upon request use the public path to map to the private path and start the download yourself.
3. Is as safe as you make it, but nothing is 100% safe so if you are storing sensitive data use something that is well build and documented

Comment: thank you for your answer , isn't possible to read text content of binary files?

Comment: It's a binary file. when you open it with a text editor you're seeing the interpretation of the file by the editor. You can save it contents to a plain text file but if you are having encoding issues most likely it will break it. Why not simply store the blob object on the database or store the file somewhere safer in your file system?